# JavaScript Dark Mode is Affecting My AOS?

Tags: javascript, aos.js

hello, newbie here.

So I'm working on my portfolio website(local) and I've added AOS(https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/) and a dark mode(https://dev.to/ananyaneogi/create-a-dark-light-mode-switch-with-css-variables-34l8) in my scripts.

Before adding the dark mode, the animated scrolls worked.

After I added the dark mode, my website no longer animates the fades automatically when it's first loaded or when it's refreshed.

Ex. My About Me section is shown when the site is loaded/refreshed; when it should have been hidden and only fades in when scrolled into.

How do I fix this? (if there's no solution I can just live with this minor bug lmao)

Example of the fade on the h2 tag:

```
<div data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-duration="1000" data-aos-easing="ease-in-out"
     data-aos-mirror="true" data-aos-once="false" class="aos-init aos-animate">
     <h2>About Me</h2>
</div>
```

My JavaScript file:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    setTimeout(function() { AOS.refresh(); }, 500);
});

// Dark Mode Switcher
// Source: https://dev.to/ananyaneogi/create-a-dark-light-mode-switch-with-css-variables-34l8
var toggleSwitch = document.querySelector('.theme-switch input[type="checkbox"]');
const currentTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme');

if (currentTheme) {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', currentTheme);

    if (currentTheme === 'dark') {
        toggleSwitch.checked = true;
    }
}

function switchTheme(e) {
    if (e.target.checked) {
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
        localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark');
    }
    else {
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light');
        localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light');
    }
}
window.addEventListener('load', AOS.refresh)
toggleSwitch.addEventListener('change', switchTheme, false);
```

Comment: is this happening locally or on the server?

Comment: Ooops forgot to mention that, it's happening locally

Answer (score 0):

It is a common issue of AOS, when you first load a website it may happen after a change in css, in your case when your trigger dark mode.

try forcing the page to reload after you change to dark mode with `window.location.reload()`

```
function switchTheme(e) {
    if (e.target.checked) {
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
        localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark');
        window.location.reload()

    }
    else {
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light');
        localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light');
        window.location.reload()
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't fix the problem . Reloading the page still shows the hidden <h2> tag, and only fades in/out when I scroll past it and scroll back towards it

Answer (score 0):

If you use any kind of switch then try it,

```
             <DarkModeSwitch
              className={darkMode ? 'dark__icon' : 'light__icon'}
              checked={darkMode}
              onClick={() => toggleTheme() + window.location.reload()}
              />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).